# How to use @Autowired instead of manually loading Spring beans?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jndi, autowired

I have a small Java application which connects to a MySQL database. For database connectivity **ONLY**, I'd like to use Spring to manage a JNDI based connection pool.

I have a working implementation for the above but this requires manually loading the JNDI connection bean, whereas I'd like to use @Autowired.

**How can I convert my working code to one that uses `@Autowired` to get the JNDI connection ?**

This is my beans.xml file (inside src/main/resources folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns= ....>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/Database"/>
    </bean>

   <bean id="databaseMapper2Impl" 
      class="com.dataaccess.DatabaseMapper2Impl">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>

</beans>
```

The is a section of my `DatabaseMapper2Impl` class:

```
public class DatabaseMapper2Impl {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public OrderDTO getOrder(String orderNumber, String envToUse) {

        String getOrderSql = "SELECT * FROM REPORTING.ORDER where ORDER_NUMBER = ? limit 1";
        List<OrderDTO> orders = jdbcTemplateObject.query(getOrderSql, new Object[] { orderNumber }, new OrderMapper());
        if (orders == null || orders.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return orders.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class where the JNDI connection bean is manually instantiated:

```
public class DataDelegateImpl {

    public OrderDTO getOrder(String orderNumber, String envToUse) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        DatabaseMapper2Impl x = (DatabaseMapper2Impl) context.getBean("databaseMapper2Impl");
        return x.getOrder(orderNumber, envToUse);
    }
}
```

Comment: What annotations are you using for this service?  Doesn't seem like the beans are discoverable by Spring based on what you have there.

Comment: Not using any annotations. Beans are loading using: `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml")`;

Answer (score 0):

In order for Spring to manage the instantiation and injection of your `DatabaseMapper2Impl`bean, you will have to create an `ApplicationContext`, and declare the bean in that context, exactly as you have done.

If the question is just how to avoid using XML for that declaration, you could annotate `DatabaseMapper2Impl` with `@Component` and instead use

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DatabaseMapper2Impl.class);
```

to create the context.

If you really need to have the `DatabaseMapper2Impl` `@Autowired` into an instance of `DataDelegateImpl`, then that instance would also have to be controlled by Spring, so you'd have to create the context at a higher level and make the `DataDelegateImpl` a bean as well.